# Find determinant of $B$ when $B=2A+A^{-1}-I$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

> Let $A$ be a $4\times 4$ real matrix with eigenvalues $1,\ -1,\ 2,\ -2$. If $$B=2A+A^{-1}-I$$ then determinant of $B$ is?

We are provided with eigenvalues then from Cayley Hamilton theorem, $A$ satisfies its characteristics equation, $$(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)=0$$hence $$A^4-5A^2+4I=0$$

Now how do I get that $B$ as $2A+A^{-1}-I$, I don't know please help.

Comment: Note that if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $Bx = (2\lambda + 1/\lambda - 1)x$. This allows you to compute the four eigenvalues of $B$ directly from the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible to solve this without picking a basis, but I can't think of such a solution.

Basically, because $B$ is a polynomial in $A$, it is simultaneously diagonalizable with $A$. So we can simply write $A = \operatorname{diag}(-2,-1,1,2)$ and then $B = \operatorname{diag}(-11/2,-4,2,7/2)$. Then $\det(B) = 154$.

Comment: $B$ is not polynomial in $A$, since it contains a $A^{-1}$ term. The important thing is that $B$ commutes with $A$.

Comment: $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $A$ (rearrange $A^4 - 5A^2 + 4I = 0$).

Comment: Uh, didn't think about that, you are right!